# PHP broken output flush / sleep

Tags: php, flush, output-buffering

So I have this code:

```
@ini_set("output_buffering", "Off");
@ini_set('implicit_flush', 1);
@ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 0);
@ini_set('max_execution_time',1500);
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header('X-Accel-Buffering: no');
```

~snip~

```
echo "Number Echos<br />"; // echo
for ($i = 0; $i < 42; $i++) { // send 41
  echo "Number". $i ." sent!<br>"; // echo this * the above
  if(sleep(4)!=0) 
  {
    echo "Error"; 
    break;
  }
  flush();
  ob_flush();
}
```

The code worked fine until about 2 weeks ago. Now the code times out the page. If I remove the `flush()` it then outputs the above as one chunk after loading it all (IE waits then outputs all 41 instead of 1 at a time). Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.

`Apache Version 2.2.29
PHP Version 5.4.35`

Comment: Try adding `flush` and `ob_flush` after echo'ing error in a loop and see, where it takes you.

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys. @RyanVincent - same result. Tomasz Struczyński - Internal Server Error.

Comment: @RyanVincentPHP was updated but then reverted, tried on multiple hosts issue persists